# How to pass a parameter name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get a handler to a variable dynamically in JavaScript? I think this won't make sense so here's what I'm trying to do.

I'm using [JQuery Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) to generate graphs in my web app. Everything works fine until I have two graphs in the same page.

I get the data from the database using c# and convert it into a JavaScript array and write onto the page like this.

HTML/C#:

```
@{
        KII.Models.JsonPerformGraphData items = new KII.Models.JsonPerformGraphData();

        foreach (KII.Models.PerformanceGraphItem item in Model.PerformanceGraphItems)
        {
            items.Add(item);
        }

        <script type="text/javascript">

      @Html.Raw("var pgdata"+Model.Id+" = ")  @Html.Raw(items.toJson()) ;

        </script>
    }
```

Then, I call a method on document ready to draw the graph

JavaScript:

```
if ($(".PerformanceGraph")) {
        $(".PerformanceGraph").livequery(function () {
            //Display the graph for risk and reward.
            var options = { series: {
                bars: { show: true, barWidth: 0.45, align: "center" }
            },
                legend: {
                    show: true, position: "ne", backgroundOpacity: 0, container: $("#PerformanceGraphLegend")
                },
                multiplebars: true
            };


            var dataArray = $(this).attr('data-array');//I get the name of the variable as String.
            $.plot($(".PerformanceGraph"), pgdata, options);
        });
    }
```

`pgdata` from javascript must match `"var pgdata"+Model.Id+"` from HTML/C#.

How can I get the variable that the HTML/C# code spits out to the HTML?

Comment: Couldn't you just output something like this instead? `plotMyJson({json from c#...});` and then create a `plotMyJson` function in js?

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate the variable name together and "eval" it.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Comment: changing it to `$.plot($(this), eval(dataArray), options);` worked. I see eval is thought to be evil though.

Comment: eval is very evil, and is (almost) never the right way to accomplish whatever you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pgdata = {};
@Html.Raw("pgdata["+Model.Id+"] = ")  @Html.Raw(items.toJson()) ;
</script>
```

and then in javascript you simply iterate over the keys in pgdata:

```
for (k in pgdata) {
    $.plot($(".PerformanceGraph"), pgdata[k], options);
}
```

Comment: The HTML/C# code gets executed several times. I think `var pgdata = {};` will clear the array after each execution.

Comment: still, this general approach is what you're looking for.  Instantiate and assign pgdata somewhere earlier, or do something like `if (! ('pgdata' in window)) { pgdata = {}; }`